# Statically obtain size of flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a widget that receives a generic widget. Then create a Row of multiple elements of that received widget. (roughly speaking)

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List<Widget> children = [];
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    children.add(
      Transform.rotate(
        angle = math.pi / 4,
        widget
      )
    );
  }
  return Row(
    children: children
  );
}
```

I want to get the width of the "widget" without using global keys and without attaching it to the widget tree (unless the recommendation is clean, i.e., not attaching an invisible widget in a stack to get the `element.size.width`).

All solutions I found online required that the target widget be attached to the widget tree.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to attach it first. Because a widget's size is often dependant on its parent

Comment: how can we identify when the parent is dependent on child's size or vice versa?